# Spring Keycloak Bearer only

Tags: spring, keycloak

Iam developing a angular webapp which is connected to a java (spring framework) backend. Authentication is done via a keycloak server.

On my local machine with the embedded tomcat server the angular application and the spring application runs without errors.

For deployment i need to use the old fashioned way by using an existing tomcat server.

The angular frontend is available in the ROOT directory via http://myurl/
The spring backend is placed as war file and reachable via http://myurl/api/

Everything works on the server except the authentication part.
Angular app is able to login via redirect etc. and gets an access token.
This token is transmitted on a request to the spring backend. 
But the backend return a not authorized message.

Any help is apriciated!

Message is:

> Unable to authenticate using the Authorization header

I have created a SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider
                = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(
                new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(
                new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*")
                .authenticated()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Added this line to the application properties

```
keycloak 
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://authserver.net/auth
keycloak.realm=myRealm keycloak.bearer-only=true 
keycloak.resource=myclient 
keycloak.cors=true
```

And added this dependancies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling the csrf token solved this issue.

Example:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      super.configure(http);
      http.authorizeRequests()
      http
          .csrf()
          .disable()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/*")
          .authenticated()
          .anyRequest()
```